# Examples of operator theory on Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

> $(1)$ If $T \in B(H)$ is self-adjoint and $T \neq 0$ then $T^n \neq 0$ $(a)$for $n=2,4,8,16,...
> (b)$ for every $n$
>
> $(2)$ Show that any $T \in B(H)$ can be uniquely expressed as $T=T_1+iT_2$ where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are self-adjoint.
>
> $(3)$ If $T$ is self-adjoint operator on $H$.show that $$ \|T\|= \sup \bigg\{ \frac{|\langle Tx,x\rangle|}{\|x\|^2}:x\neq 0 \bigg\}=a$$
>
> $(4)$ Show by an example composition of two positive operator need not positive operator.
>
> $(5)$  show that an isometric linear operator $T:H \to H$ which is not unitary maps the Hilbert space H onto a proper closed subspace of H.

I tried $(3)$ I already proved that $a \leq \|T\| $

In $(4)$ I know that the linear map represented by the matrix

$ \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{pmatrix}$

where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ $T$ is positive iff $b=c$, $a\geq 0$,$b \geq 0$ and  $ad \geq b^2$ but I am fails to find such matrix.Is it possible?
In $(1),(2)$ and $(5)$ I have no idea so please give me hints and some explanation for all these questions.Please help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Regarding (1), choose $x$ such that $Tx\neq 0$. Then look at $<Tx,Tx>$.

Comment: @Thomas What is the use of self-adjoint there?

Comment: Generally, $$\langle Tx,Tx\rangle = \langle T^\ast Tx,x\rangle.$$ Now if $T = T^\ast$ ...

Comment: The following may help (see proposition 2.4.3 in Kadison and Ringrose):

If $S$ and $T$ are bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $\langle Sx, x \rangle = \langle Tx, x \rangle$ for all $x \in \mathcal{H}$, then $S=T$.

Comment: For (ii) try setting
$$ T = \frac{ (T + T^*) }{2} + i \frac{ (T - T^*) }{ 2i } $$